# Terminate specific ec2 instance in an autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I've created aws cloudwatch alarm based on ASG's group metrics cpuutilization. It sends an email alert email whenever cpuutilization exceeds more than 99% for more than an hour.

Is there a way to execute an event/action that will terminate specific ec2 instances that triggered the alarm? These instances hang and has to be terminated.

Comment: It is not possible to write one alarm for an Auto Scaling group that then performs an action on a _specific_ instance. The action can only relate to the Auto Scaling group as a whole (eg scale-out, scale-in).

Answer (score 3):

I would create an additional alarm that would terminate any instance that reaches 99% cpu for an hour. This is directly supported by CloudWatch.

From **Create Alarms to Stop, Terminate, Reboot, or Recover an Instance:**

> Using Amazon CloudWatch alarm actions, you can create alarms that automatically stop, terminate, reboot, or recover your EC2 instances. You can use the reboot and recover actions to automatically reboot those instances or recover them onto new hardware if a system impairment occurs.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html

Comment: This only applies to alarm at instance level but not for the scaling group

Answer (score 0):

I feel possible solution for this requirement is to write AWS Cli script which would run probably every 15 mins and get list of all EC2 instances running and then terminate if needed. Also, need historical info for ec2's w/c cpu is at 100% for more than 45mins

Comment: Yeah, that's possible but that would be outside cloudwatch w/c I'm interested in, minimizing additional failure points